# Place Comma Between Two Concatenated Arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays of user id's which are gathered from two MYSQL queries and then treated as:

```
$var1 = implode(",",$result1);
$var2 = implode(",",$result2);
```

This gives me something like:

```
$var1 = 132, 567, 345 
$var2 = 12, 934, 302
```

I then concatenate these two variables with:

```
$varfinal = $var1 . $var2;
```

The trouble I'm having is there is no comma between the end of $var1 and the beginning of $var2 so $varfinal ends up with:

```
132, 567, 34512, 934 302
```

When what I need it to be is:

```
132, 567, 345, 12, 934 302
```

Can someone show me how I can add a comma to separate the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$varfinal = $var1 . ', ' . $var2;
```

You just concenate $var1, a comma and the $var2 - variable.

If $result1 or $result2 is empty - you could do something like this instead:

```
$varfinal = implode(',', array_merge($result1, $result2));
```

Comment: And if `$var2` is empty, or `$result2` is empty ?

Answer (score 2):

Are `$result{n}` array?

Use `array_merge()`, then `implode`

```
$a = array_merge($result1, $result2);
$string = implode(",", $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
$varfinal = $var1 .','. $var2;
```